# Countdown timer with random number generator

Tags: php, javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I am running a sweepstakes like thing and want my users to all be able to load the page and have the exact same countdown and number generator running. I tried this in AS3 but each user caches their own swf file and gets a different result from the random number generator, and the as3 countdown is a few seconds off from each user. How would I go about making a countdown that is the exact same for each user looking at it at the same time and then a random number generator where every user will see the same result it gives? Is it even possible?

Sorry I wasnt clear on this. I would like to have it where the viewers could see the number being generated when the timer runs out. Kind of like watching the lotto on TV. Again, not sure if this is possible.

I have looked around, I know as3, some php, and some javascript. I have given up on doing this in flash.

Comment: is there one random number at the end?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have it generate a random number from say 1 - 300. It will be the value everyone sees.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand correctly what you want, store a `random value` (RV) every time someone accesses the page associated with a UNIX timestamp in seconds. Make `time` column unique, then if another request is made the same second, the random number is going to be taken out of the database.

Comment: What I would like is to have a countdown. Say 1 month. And at the end of the countdown, have it run a random number generator where if multiple users are on the site looking at it - it will print the same number out for each user. They are all seeing the same number generator. In flash, the generator worked fine but it was cached on each computer so it ran separately on each computer and each computer got a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Store the timer result in a table, show users the stored random number. Then when needed simply create another random number, store again, show user. Repeat.

Comment: I was hoping to have some sort of animated thing where they could all watch the number be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Every user that come to that page , first print the time from the server so every user that will come and if your server time is 12:00 am for example , you will show him 12:00 am.

And then with Ajax refresh this time every X seconds ajax will send a request to the server and the server will tell you the time to display.

Keep the random logic on your server and when your application logic will say to change to a different number the server will return a different number and your clients will get it on the next pull ( ajax ) .

I hope that answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with flash, but what I would do is make the countdown happen client side using javascript's getUTCSeconds(), getUTCMinutes(), getUTCHours() etc to figure out current time verses end time of the counter (end time in universal time code).

Then you could use php to generate the random numbers (and a corresponding remaining time associated with it? how often do you want these?) and store it in a location for later retrieval (database, or file or some such). You could use ajax to grab the random number at the specified times

for more about js date/time functions w3schools has a pretty good resource: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Actionscript has a Date class that does all that so there's no need to involve javascript.

Comment: Ok, well I suppose the idea is still there, compare current utc time to utc end time would be the best way to ensure everybody is on the same count down

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.
All logic should be stored on the server side. Use Flash only to show results.

Countdown: create it with php, store on the server side in the storage (database, memory, files, whatever). All clients (written on Flash) request counter value and display the counter on the client side starting from the value taken from server.

Lotto results are also generated on the server and passed to the clients. On the first hand you may generate intermediate results on the server and read them one by one by the clients, but I'd generate all results at once and pass them to the client.

Intermediate results can then be synchronized with the counter.

Comment: I follow. Use php to make the countdown and generate the random number, then use flash to display after it is saved server side.